# Getting errors when I compare elements in two vectors - am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, vector

The task is pretty simple: create a program that will tell the user if a sentence he or she enters is the same backwards and forwards (in terms of words used, not spelling). For example, `"I am that am I"` (please ignore how grammatically nonsensical this may be). So I decided to create two string vectors - one that would store the original sentence, and another that would be the sentence reversed. The elements of each vector would be strings containing the words of the sentence, e.g `["I", "am", "that", "am", I"]`, excluding any spaces in the string.

I'm stuck in a preliminary state of solving this problem - comparing the elements of these two vectors. Here's my code below (note that sentence is the first vector, and reverseString is the second vector, containing the elements in reverse order):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
            // The below output is for debugging purposes
            cout << "The index is " << i
                 << " and the original string at this location is " << sentence[i]
                 << " and the reverse string is " << reverseString[i] << endl;

            if (sentence[i] == reverseString[i]) {
                cout << reverseString[i] << "---" << sentence[i] <<  endl;
                cout << "A match!" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << reverseString[i] << "---" << sentence[i] << endl;
                cout << "Not a match!" << endl;
            }
        }
```

Bizarrely, the above code seems to work accurately for elements in indexes 1 to `vector.size()-2` (remember that indexes in vectors for c++ begin and zero). But index 0 or `vector.size()-1` - i.e. the first and last elements of each vector - always yields a `"Not a match!"`, no matter what the sentence. Everything in between is accurately compared, but those two positions aren't.

This is a very strange bug. Maybe my error lies in creating the second vector? This is the code I used:

```
    int t = sentence.size() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
        reverseString[i] = sentence[t];
        t--;
    }
```

Am I inadvertently mutating something I shouldn't be for the first and last elements, in a way I can't quite see? Is my logic flawed? Please let me know what you think :)

**EDIT**: I am posting a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example** of my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    cout << "Please input a sentence - no preceding or trailing spaces."
            " It will be analyzed accordingly: ";

    getline(cin, input);

    string secondString = "";
    secondString[0] = input[0];

    int i = 0; 
    for (i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++) {
        // the below strips a string of punctuation if there is any, 
        // as these characters would mess up the comparison.

        if (input[i] == ',' || input[i] == ';' || input[i] == ':' ||
            input[i] == '.' || input[i] == '?' || input[i] == '!') {
        } else {
            secondString = secondString + input[i];
        }
    }

    // now stuff the individual words in the string into a vector
    vector<string> sentence;

    // now we are going to stuff each word into a vector
    string word;
    stringstream ss(secondString);

    while (getline(ss, word, ' ')) {
        sentence.push_back(word);
    }

    // now for Task 1 - we will create a second vector that is reversed.
    // Then compare both vectors - if identical, note it. 

    vector<string> reverseString;
    reverseString = sentence; 

    int t = sentence.size() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
        reverseString[i] = sentence[t];
        t--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
        cout << "The index is " << i
             << " and the original string at this location is " << sentence[i]
             << " and the reverse string is " << reverseString[i] << endl;

        if (sentence[i] == reverseString[i]) {
            cout << reverseString[i] << "---" << sentence[i] <<  endl;
            cout << "A match!" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << reverseString[i] << "---" << sentence[i] << endl;
            cout << "Not a match!" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `sentence`?

Comment: And, was `reverseString` resized before assigning its elements?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Post the full code of the function. We cannot see the definitions for you variables, every detail matters.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CoAsdN0BB3LFUS9q). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using two vectors would seem like overkill. Use one and compare elements 0 & n-1, 1 & n-2, etc.

Comment: Hi guys, I've posted a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example - thank you for taking a look. @Steve, maybe you're right -  I'll experiment with just one vector.

Comment: @ChrisT You still haven't included `<string>`. Surely it doesn't compile.

Comment: Neither is it *minimal*.

Comment: @erip - it does compile without the string library, but I added it and I'm still getting the error, weirdly.

Comment: @ChrisT Typically MVCEs should be 10-20 lines of code. Not hard and fast, but any more than that and many won't want to spend time.

Comment: @erip - Duly noted - I'll see if I can cut this down and I'll repost it accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisT Cutting it down will help you find the part that's broken, too. Sometimes creating an MVCE will help you find the problems, which is the goal. :)

Comment: For one thing, `secondString[0] = input[0];`is invalid when `secondString` is empty. Likewise `for (i = 0; i <= input.length();` should stop **before** reaching `input.length()`.

Comment: @BoPersson I think you caught it! I changed <= to < and the code is now matching correctly. As for secondString[0] = input[0]; I'm a tad confused as to what you mean, but I'll experiment with using a " " as opposed to "".

Comment: @Chris - The thing with `secondString[0]` is that when the string is empty, none of the elements can be indexed, not even the first, because there is nothing there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **undefined behaviour** because of the comparison in this line:

> ```
> for (i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++)
> ```

Undefined behaviour happens as soon as the loop body tries to access `input[i]` while `i` is equal to `input.length()`. Make it:

```
for (i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
```

It's just bad luck that the program didn't crash, or else you may have noticed the error earlier.

What happened to me when I tried it was that a superfluous space character was attached to `secondString`, which eventually caused the last element in `sentence` to have an extra space at the end, so the first and last words could never be equal.

---

Also note that the sentence-comparison code itself is too complicated, because you can achieve your goal in a much simpler manner with [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal), `std::vector`'s reverse iterator obtained by the [`rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) member function, and splitting the range in half, like in this example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool compare(std::vector<std::string> const& sentence)
{
    // returns true if the range from the first to the middle element
    // is equal to the range from the last to the middle element

    return std::equal(
        sentence.begin(),
        sentence.begin() + sentence.size() / 2,
        sentence.rbegin()
    );
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> const sentence1 = { "I", "am", "that", "am", "I" };
    std::vector<std::string> const sentence2 = { "am", "that", "am", "I" };
    std::vector<std::string> const sentence3 = { };
    std::vector<std::string> const sentence4 = { "I", "am", "that", "that", "am", "I" };
    std::vector<std::string> const sentence5 = { "I" };

    std::cout << compare(sentence1) << "\n"; // true
    std::cout << compare(sentence2) << "\n"; // false
    std::cout << compare(sentence3) << "\n"; // true
    std::cout << compare(sentence4) << "\n"; // true
    std::cout << compare(sentence5) << "\n"; // true
}
```

This solution takes only one `std::vector` and does not perform more comparisons than necessary; when the middle element of a sentence is reached, the result is already known.

In contrast, your original code needlessly iterates the entire sentence:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
> ```

Comment: This was exactly it. Thank you for this. I thought I was going crazy because visibly the strings seemed identical - I would have never caught that superfluous character otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> For one thing, secondString[0] = input[0];is invalid when secondString
>   is empty. Likewise for (i = 0; i <= input.length(); should stop before
>   reaching input.length(). – Bo Persson 12 mins ago

Bo Persson's comment fixes your problem.